# Heuristic solutions for distinguishable job scheduling problem

Tags: optimization, reference-request, terminology

I currently am trying to develop a heuristic solution for the following problem, which probably has been looked at before, but I haven't found any material on it. I'd like to know if this problem has a canonical name, and if there are any references in which I can read about it.

> I have n employees and m clients.
>
> - Each client and employee has a collection of time intervals detailing their availability.
> - Each client has a list of employees that they would like to meet, in priority order. Each meeting has a fixed time interval.
>
> I'd like to find a way to schedule client-employee meetings to
> maximize the number of employees that each client can meet off their
> list.

Comment: It looks like job scheduling with dependencies. The priority order is a dependency. e.g. on a building site concreting, brick laying, plumbing, tiling etc depend on the job before them. The availability of each trades person are constraints.

Comment: I my opinion, the only way to solve this is brute force. Evolutionary algorithms (like firefly) can do the job to some extent. If the requirement that the "meeting length is fixed" is weakened (for example, you add some randomness to the problem), then the problem is easier. Check, for example, https://ris.utwente.nl/ws/portalfiles/portal/253274593/Skutella2014stochastic.pdf and http://page.math.tu-berlin.de/~skutella/SchulzSkut-SIDMA02.pdf